# Yet another C++ cin loop issue

Tags: c++

**Update**

I found the cause of the problem. I have been experimenting with the [fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/) shell. I saw the comment that said someone had successfully run my code on a Mac, and decided to try it in a standard bash shell. It worked perfectly. So, no more fish shell I guess. :)

I would still appreciate knowing how and why cin works the way it does. This is the main part of my question.

---

I have run into a popular problem: using `cin` in a loop. The code is straightforward, but I cannot find a solution. The answers Google have provided me are varied, but usually involve some combination of `cin.clear()`, `cin.ignore()`, and `cin.get()`. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a combination or ordering of those that fix my problem. Moreover, I find it frustrating that I don't have a complete understanding of the function of `cin`. I'd rather not use trial and error to fix this. I want to understand exactly what's going on.

**What Should Happen**

When I run my code, I should see a prompt with a list of options. I should be able to type a character which will run one of the options. Then, it should display the prompt again and repeat the process until I select the *Exit* option.

**What Actually Happens**

As soon as I run the code, it prints the prompt to the screen an arbitrary number of times and eventually stops halfway through the prompt. Then I am unable to do anything but kill it with `^C`.

```
$ ./run

Choose an option:
[A]dd a score
[R]emove a player
[E]xit

    : That is not a valid input.

[repeated a bunch of times]

Choose an option:
[A]dd a score
[R]emove a player
[E]xit

    : That is not a valid input.


Choose ^C
$
```

**My Question**

What causes cin to do that? As an experienced Java developer (but a beginner C++ developer), I'm familiar with the concepts of buffers and streams and such, but I have no idea how `cin` works. I know that `cin.clear()` clears an error state, and `cin.ignore()` ignores a number of characters in the stream. My Google-fu has thus far been unable to find a concise reference.

*Why does `cin` act the way it does? How should one visualize what happens under the hood when using `cin` in a loop? What is the most elegant way to implement this infinite menu idea in C++?*

**My Code**

Here is a simplified version of my code, which produces the exact same problem as the full version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    //infinite menu 
    char input;
    while(true) {

        //prompt
        cout << "\n\nChoose an option:\n";
        cout << "[A]dd a score\n";
        cout << "[R]emove a player\n";
        cout << "[E]xit\n";
        cout << "\n\t: ";

        //input
        cin >> input;

        //decide what the input means
        switch(input) {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                cout << "Add a score.\n";
                break;
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                cout << "Remove a player.\n";
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                cout << "Program Complete.\n";
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "That is not a valid input.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run with:

```
$ g++ Test.cpp -o run
$ ./run
```

I'm running `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: fwiw, I ran this on my Mac (llvm4.1) without issue at all. (apart from the annoyance of having to tap <return> after the selection char)

Comment: It shouldn't have a problem reading one character unless it's EOF, or had a non-input-related problem. The only thing I'd suggest is using `ignore` after the switch in order to clear it out (i.e. entering "hello" doesn't immediately go through 5 times, only once for 'h').

Comment: For starters, in your default case print out what 'input' actually is... That way you can at least see what is going on.

Comment: Big big mistake: Unguarded input operation. Don't do it. You mustn't read the `input` variable if the previous input operation didn't succeed, but you never check for that.

Comment: +1 Nice question presentation.

Comment: @FaddishWorm I've done that. The inputs are either '', or ' '.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and don't extract tokens directly from `std::cin`. Instead, read line by line with `getline` and *then* interpret each line. Also, you must always evaluate the result of an input operation in a boolean context, or you will not be able to handle arbitrary input correctly.

For a test, your program must survive if you call `echo "abc" | ./run`. This should always be one of your first tests.

Now, on to the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        if (line.empty()) { continue; }


        if (line == "A" || line == "a") { /* ... */ continue; }

        if (line == "R" || line == "r") { /* ... */ continue; }

        if (line == "E" || line == "e") { break; }

        std::cout << "Sorry, I did not understand.\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";
}
```

Comment: BTW, the `if` expression can be simplified by assigning a `char` value to the first character in the line and using `toupper` or `tolower` on the character before the comparisons.

Comment: I'd prefer `if`/`else if` to `continue` and `break` in this case.

Comment: @Kerrek I like your solution. It's clean and simple. Still, I like to understand the "why". Why does the `cin >>` construct exist if it's bad practice to use it? It's taught in every intro C++ course I've seen. (Not that they ever teach good practice in class...)

Comment: @GriffGeorge: If I had a penny for every broken piece of I/O code that crosses StackOverflow, I'd be rich. So I haven't got a lot of faith in anyone's teaching of C++ I/O. I also have interviewed several allegedly "experienced C++ programmers" who just don't get this right. This is quickly becoming one of my biggest pet peeves, I'm telling you... anyway, what's wrong is that when an extraction fails you have to jump through a whole lot of hoops to "resume" reading from a stream, and that's a lot more uncomfortable than processing each line...

Comment: ... Line extraction can basically never fail prematurely (it'll only fail at the end of the stream, when it should), and usually people *want* to parse "commands" which consist of entire lines (e.g. until the user presses Enter). So the split of reading lines from `cin` and then parsing each line (discarding invalid ones) is far more natural to what most use cases want to accomplish.

Comment: Cool. So it is agreed that using `getline()` for input is the "right" thing to do, and `cin` should be reserved for specific use cases. I suppose the other problem with learning the right thing to do in this situation is: who ever asks for this kind of menu except programming teachers!? I can't think of a single case in real life when a selection menu like this is the best interface.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GriffGeorge: Just to be clear, you will of course use `getline` on `cin`. I'm just discouraging using the shift operator `>>` directly on `cin`. Leave the shift operator for string streams made from each line individually.